# OpenDDS: how to communicate two hosts through public network (WAN)

Tags: networking, data-distribution-service, wan, opendds

Rcently, I succeeded in communicating two hosts in same subnet by OpenDDS.
However, I want to communicate other two hosts through public network or WAN. It doesn't work.
How can I solve this problem??

Here is my communication enviroment:

I have two hosts.
HostA is AWS(Amazon Web Service) and Host B is my Destktop. Also, two hosts has public IP address and disable firewall. I already checked whether the specific port number was available by telnet command. like this:

```
$ telnet <HostA IP's> 12345
```

and it is fine connetion.

I used OpenDDS-3.11 and `$OpenDDS_HOME/tests/DCPS/Messenger` 's example.

In HostA, enable

```
$ DCPSInfoRepo -ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:12345
```

Subscriber operate like this:

```
$ ./subscriber -DCPSConfigFile sub_multicast.ini
```

In HostB,

Directory is same subsceriber and then publisher operate like this:

```
$ ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo <HostA's IP>:12345 -DCPSConfigFile pub_multicast.ini
```

Publisher's return error message here:

```
$ ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo <HostA' IP>:12345 -DCPSConfigFile pub_multicast.ini
Starting publisher
(3074|140050504111936) NOTICE: using DCPSInfoRepo value from command option (overrides value if it's in config file).
Starting publisher with 1 args
(3074|140050504111936) EXCEPTION, ERROR: InfoRepoDiscovery::get_dcps_info: failed to resolve ior -
system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/TRANSIENT:1.0'
OMG minor code (2), described as 'No usable profile in IOR.', completed = NO

(3074|140050504111936) ERROR: DomainParticipantFactoryImpl::create_participant, add_domain_participant returned invalid id.
publisher.cpp:66: main() ERROR: create_participant failed!
ERROR: InfoRepoDiscovery::~InfoRepoDiscovery - Exception caught during ORB shutdown: system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/BAD_INV_ORDER:1.0'
OMG minor code (4), described as 'ORB has shutdown.', completed = NO
```

What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve my problem
Just change Discovery server host and use rtps_uni.ini file.
like this:

```
DCPSInfoRepo -ORBListenEndpoints iiop://:12345
```

subscriber side:

```
./subscriber -DCPSDebugLevel=5 -DCPSInfoRepo HostA:12345 -DCPSConfigFile rtps_uni.ini
```

publisher side:

```
 ./publisher -DCPSInfoRepo HostA:12345 -DCPSConfigFile rtps_uni.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in same question. I wanted to do similar run from AWS to my application.

Currently using websocket to bridge the router Nat problems. I am running the dcpsInfoRepo in local network. But I have discovery problem in devices in different subnet. I wasn't sure multicast was supported by all routers. So using tcp connection.